# Animating nested children's properties using a style [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

I have a button with an image in it. The image's source is just an SVG that I have converted into XAML code. How do I animate the color of that SVG.

I want to create a style that changes the color of the image that I can use on all buttons with SVG images.

Here is the button's code:

```
<Button Background="Transparent"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Style="{StaticResource VideoControl}">
                            <Image>
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <DrawingImage>
                                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                            <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V29 H26 V0 H0 Z">
                                                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="White" Geometry="F1 M26,29z M0,0z M24,11.0359C26.6667,12.5755,26.6667,16.4245,24,17.9641L6.75,27.9234C4.08334,29.463,0.75,27.5385,0.75,24.4593L0.75,4.54071C0.75,1.46151,4.08333,-0.462994,6.75,1.07661L24,11.0359z" />
                                                </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            </DrawingGroup>
                                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    </DrawingImage>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </Button>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="VideoControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

            <!--This is done to prevent the Window Control Buttons from being focused-->
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>

            <!--This overrides the default behaviour of the button when hovering over it-->
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                                Padding="0"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <!--Animations-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty=""
                                    To="#F0AD2B"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

As you can see. I tried fiddling around with `Storyboard.TargetProperty` but I couldn't reach the bursh's color of the image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the GeometryDrawing's Brush to the `Foreground` property of the Button

```
<GeometryDrawing
    Brush="{Binding Foreground,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
    .../>
```

and animate that property

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="VideoControl">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                            To="#F0AD2B"
                            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

There should also be a `<Trigger.ExitActions>` that stops the `BeginStoryboard` or animates back to white.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind stranger. This works perfectly! I'm fairly new to XAML. I should try to learn more about binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `Brush` to a property of the `Button`. The below example uses the `Foreground` property. If you want to decouple the color of the image from the `Button.Foreground` you should extend `Button` and create an `ImageButton` that defines e.g. `ImageForeground` and `ImageBackground` properties that you can bind to instead.

Then use an `EventTrigger` to animate on `MouseEnter` (to start the animation) and `MouseLeave` (to stop the animation using a `StopStoryboard` or to revert the animation using a `BeginStoryboard`).
The `ColorAnimation` target is the `Button.Foreground.Color` property (the `SolidColorBrush.Color` property).

```xml
<!-- Control the image color by setting the Foreground property -->
<Button Background="Transparent"
        Foreground="OrangeRed"
        BorderThickness="0">

  <!-- Dynamic content -->
  <Image>
    <Image.Source>
      <DrawingImage>
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
          <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V29 H26 V0 H0 Z">
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
              <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}"
                               Geometry="F1 M26,29z M0,0z M24,11.0359C26.6667,12.5755,26.6667,16.4245,24,17.9641L6.75,27.9234C4.08334,29.463,0.75,27.5385,0.75,24.4593L0.75,4.54071C0.75,1.46151,4.08333,-0.462994,6.75,1.07661L24,11.0359z" />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
      </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
  </Image>

  <Button.Style>

    <!-- Reusable Style -->
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Border Name="border"
                    Padding="0"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MouseOverAnimation">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="#F0AD2B"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                  </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
              </EventTrigger>

              <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverAnimation" />
              </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I did as you and [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) suggested. It works perfectly!